# Cannot send image in base64 format with XHR to aws S3 in android(react-native)

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest

I got very strange issue: we have scan functionality for documents in our app and as the result scan give's me encoded base64 image with photo. Everything is good on ios platform but when I trying to send my picture on android, I get xhr.status 0 and error. Also, next strange thing is that when I starting debug mode and enable network inspection in react-native-debugger, picture is sending without errors. I was trying it on release app version, installed on my device, but still got an error with status 0

XHR request

```
export const uploadXHRImage = (url: string, data: IDataUploadImage) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    resolve('Image successfully uploaded to S3');
                } else {
                    reject(localize('failedUploadImage'));
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.ontimeout = () => reject(localize('timeoutUploadImage'));
        xhr.timeout = UPLOAD_IMAGE_TIMEOUT;
        xhr.open('PUT', url);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', data.type);
        xhr.send(data);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: Android can not process xhr send image, while image isn't saved as file in cache or other directory. Also, android needs `file://` before data. Example is here:

```
saveImage = (image: string) => {
        if (IS_IOS) {
            return `data:image/jpg;base64,${image}`;
        }

        const tempFileDirectory = `${fs.CachesDirectoryPath}`;
        const tempFilePath = `${tempFileDirectory}/${uuidv4()}.jpg`;
        fs.writeFile(tempFilePath, image, 'base64');
        return `file://${tempFilePath}`;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to header:

```
"Content-Type": 'application/json',   
"Connection": "close",
```

Comment: It doesn't help. I'm trying to add text/plain;charset-utf8 with encrtiption base64 headers, but it also doesn't work. Also, I don't understand, why enabling network inspection in my debugger helps me